# How to build .vrt of shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I've a huge number of shapefiles and I would like to create a VRT as I do with gdalbuilvrt for raster.
I find here https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet that it should be possible and the format of VRT for OGR vector files exists and is described here : http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html.

Where can I find documentation or a utility program to do that?

Comment: From your second link: `The virtual files are currently normally prepared by hand.`. ogr2ogr is not yet able to do it.

Comment: Perhaps worth making a feature request into https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/

Comment: I have added some sample vrt files in my answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200138/how-to-ignore-handle-bad-layers-in-qgis