# Is there a way to ignore the "handle bad layers" error message without removing the layers from the project?

Tags: qgis, layers

I have multiple QGIS projects that use the same base layers. I keep the QGIS projects on dropbox so I can access them from different computers. The base layers are scattered all over the place, on multiple servers, or buried deep in the files of one computer or another. Basically, the file organization here is a mess, but fixing it is a problem above my pay grade. The problem is that sometimes I want to make changes to a project when I'm not connected to one of the servers. I can get along without these layers temporarily, but I want them to be available when I reconnect to that server. I have copies of some of the base layers on dropbox with the project, but storage space is limited so this is only practical for the layers I use most frequently.

Is there a way to ignore the "handle bad layers" error message that comes up when I open a project **without** removing the layers from the project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200138/how-to-ignore-handle-bad-layers-in-qgis

Comment: This is a slightly different situation than the one described by Aaron in "How to ignore “handle bad layers” in QGIS?" He is dealing with only one project with raster layers stored at two locations. I have multiple projects,  with both vector and raster layers in more than two locations.

Comment: My solution works for any kind of datasources, and as many projects you have. Either make the project files read-only, or wrap VRT around the datasources.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on how to wrap a VRT around the datasources?

Comment: For rasters: `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate`, selecting `virtual raster` as output. For vector data, according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151290/how-to-build-vrt-of-shapefiles it has to be build manually accrding to the linked specification. You will find some examples in that page too.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It's now clear to me that the VRT method is beyond my ability. I will continue to use the cumbersome workaround of having different versions of each project.

Comment: I have added example vrt files to the linked question.

Comment: As I mentioned in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200138/how-to-ignore-handle-bad-layers-in-qgis. The change data source plugin works for me. You need to have Qgis open first and then open up a project in order to get the plugin to take over.