# QGIS Projects and files between multiple computers

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I currently run QGIS on my laptop and Mac. On my laptop I keep my Geopackage and project files in a folder on my hard drive. I have Goodsync setup to backup this folder to a shared drive on my NAS. I use QGIS on my Mac to access these project and Geopackage files from the NAS.

The issues I am running into is that after syncing I have to open QGIS to find the Gepackage files on whatever computer I am on, since the file location is different between my laptop and my mac.

Secondly, if I add a new geopackage as a layer on my laptop, then open it on my mac, I have to go an manually find it.

Is it possible to auto search for new geopackage layers?

Is there a solution for a seamless transition between two devices where I wont keep having to point each one to the updated directory?

Comment: u can't access your NAS location from your laptop i suppose ?

Comment: Correct, I take my laptop to work and on the road with me.

Comment: There's an option under project menu > properties where you can choose "relative" or "absolute" file paths. I've seen lots of posts complaining that this feature doesn't always work as expected, though. It might also help you to save some file locations as favorites in the Browser panel.

Comment: I asked a [related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209238/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-the-handle-bad-layers-error-message-without-removing); one suggestion was to use a virtual layer.

Comment: I will check out the relative file paths menu and favorites. Did you use a virtual layer? Did it achieve the results you wanted?